# Nextflow adding def function in to script

Tags: nextflow

I have got errors like .command.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('

```
/*
  * Step 3
  */

 chr_length = file(params.chr_length)


 process create_bedgraph_and_bigwig {

     publishDir "${params.outdir}/bedgraphandbigwig", mode: 'copy'

     input:
     set val(sample_id), file(vector_log) from vector_log_ch
     set val(sample_id), file(target_query_bam) from target_query_bam_ch
     file chr_length

     output:
     set val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.bedgraph.log.txt") into bed_log_ch
     set val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.bed") into bed_ch
     set val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.clean.bed") into clean_bed_ch
     set val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.fragments.bed") into fragments_bed_ch
     set val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.sorted.fragments.bed") into sorted_fragments_bed_ch


     shell:


     '''

     def fp = file(${vector_log})
     def lines = fp.readLines()
     def line3 = lines[3].split(' ')[4].toInteger()
     def line4 = lines[4].split(' ')[4].toInteger()
     def aln_sum = (10000/(line3 + line4)).toString()



     bedtools bamtobed -bedpe -i !{target_query_bam} > !{sample_id}.bed 2>!{sample_id}.bedgraph.log.txt
     awk '$1==$4 && $6-$2 < 1000 {{print $0}}' !{sample_id}.bed > !{sample_id}.clean.bed 2>!{sample_id}.bedgraph.log.txt
     cut -f 1,2,6 !{sample_id}.clean.bed > !{sample_id}.fragments.bed 2>!{sample_id}.bedgraph.log.txt
     sort -k 1,1 !{sample_id}.fragments.bed > !{sample_id}.sorted.fragments.bed

     '''

 }
```

Comment: Also, your input block defines 'sample_id' twice. You shouldn't expect to get the same 'sample_id' from both channels. What you'll find is that one 'sample_id' will simply clobber the other, but you won't know which one. To avoid surprises, what you'll need to do is join those two input channels first, i.e. `set val(sample_id), file(vector_log), file(target_query_bam) from vector_log_ch.join(target_query_bam_ch)`

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to avoid using 'def' if the variable needs to be used in a shell definition or template. I couldn't actually find this after a quick search of the documentation, but I did find this note from the author:

> Using groovy native string interpolation that would work, but when using the !{..} syntax scripts variable cannot be declared locally using the def keyword.
>
> To summarise:
>
> - script/shell variable should be defensively declared in the local scope using the def keyboard
> - do not use def when:
>
>   i. the variable needs to be referenced as a output value
>
>   ii. the variable needs to be used in a shell template

https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/678#issuecomment-386206123